# asd.jpg is not a valid JPEG file - Scandir PHP

Tags: php, jpeg, libjpeg, scandir

I have a software that upload each minute a jpeg into **FTP** account.

In PHP i make a little PHP code in crontab that take last JPEG file and performs graphics processing. This work fine.

```
$all_files = scandir("./dir/dir",1);
$last_files = $all_files[0]; //take last jpeg
..etc..
```

The problem is that sometimes the PHP Code in crontab takes a file that is still being written over FTP (so it is incomplete) and generate this error:

```
[01-Jun-2016 15:30:05 Europe/Rome] PHP Warning:  imagecreatefromjpeg(): gd-jpeg, libjpeg: recoverable error: Premature end of JPEG file in /home/asdasd/public_html/www.asdasdasdasd.com/asd/asd/cron.php on line 15
[01-Jun-2016 15:30:05 Europe/Rome] PHP Warning:  imagecreatefromjpeg(): './dir/dir/153000.jpg' is not a valid JPEG file in /home/asdasd/public_html/www.asdasdasdasd.com/asd/asd/cron.php on line 15
[01-Jun-2016 15:30:05 Europe/Rome] PHP Warning:  imagecopyresampled() expects parameter 2 to be resource, boolean given in /home/asdasd/public_html/www.asdasdasdasd.com/asd/asd/cron.php on line 17
```

**How do I add a check for scandir to catch the last complete file and not being written?**

Comment: Standard practice is to upload the file with a temporary name (e.g. `asd.jpg.part`) and then rename when the transfer is complete. You would then only scan for files ending in .jpg.

Comment: No iainn I don't read .part suffix when the file is written

Answer (score 3):

You can just check the JPEG file if it's valid before processing it (cron.php):

```
if(exif_imagetype($filepath) != IMAGETYPE_JPEG){
    // Exit the script
    exit;
}

// Your image processing code goes here...
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.exif-imagetype.php

Comment: Thanks! I try also:
`$jpeg = imagecreatefromjpeg('./asd/asd/'.$last_files);
      if(!$jpeg){ //fail } else { //image processing }`

Comment: Yes, that could work too. What's important is to verify it before processing it.